# Modulo Arithmetic in C

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm writing a program in C and there is a prompt for a number, but the number entered has to satisfy the equation

```
d * e = 1 (mod t)
```

For example, `e = 11`, and `t = 24`.

This means `d = 1 (mod 24)/11`

What exactly does `mod 24` calculate out to? As far as the math I've learned concerns, you need an additional number that 24 divides to get a remainder.

Comment: Have you searched on the web ?  You will find good explanations.

Comment: Mod has two meanings, one is a function and one is a relation.  In terms of the function, we should have have $d\cdot e \pmod t = 1$, but not $1\pmod t = d\cdot e$.

Comment: I have but none of them make much sense and usually it's along the lines of `1 mod N` instead of 1 (mod N). Is it just a matter of multiplying 1 by mod N or is there something special about it?

Comment: Slade, are you saying it's a relation and has no solution or that it's written incorrectly?